# Create an Excel PivotTable from a DataTable

Tags: c#, vsto, pivot

I have a webservice that is hosting a large mass of pricing data, and returns the data relevant to some prescribed query parameters. The data comes back as a Datatable object (in C#) - the object type itself doesn't matter so much as the fact that the data goes directly into memory and is not on a spreadsheet in the host Excel object.

Now, I want to create a pivottable off of this data.

I've been looking high and low on the web, and I can't see anyone explaining how to do this. Is it impossible? It seems foolish to suggest VSTO as the only supported way of consuming webservice data going forward, but make pivottables off of that data impossible.

The only solutions I have are kludges, and I want to make sure there isn't a graceful solution before I do one of these ugly things:

1. Dump datatable to excel sheet and point pivottable to excel range.
   This is far from ideal because I'm either doing rowwise deletion
   over the entire dataset (slow as heck) or peaking at 2x memory
   consumption
2. Dump datatable to filesystem and point pivottable to flatfile.
       This is even worse but at least doesn't have the memory drawback.

Are these really the only ways to do this operation? There has to be something more graceful.

DataTable: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx

PivotCache: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.pivottable.pivotcache(v=office.11).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Excel has to be able to see and access the data to make a PivotTable from it.  So you have to make sure that the data is someplace that the PivotTable loader can read.  Further, Excel is COM-based and can neither see nor process .NET objects.

It's pretty much just that simple.

Your choices are:

1. Load the data into an Excel range
2. Save the data to a file
3. Store the data into a database (Access, SQL Server, etc.)
4. Store the data in a data warehouse (SSAS, offline Cube, etc.)

That's it.  The only other remotely possible way would be to implement the COM interfaces necessary to present as an OLE DB or an ODBC data source, but that would be one heck of a lot of work.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but surely there is more to it - if I have the data in an Excel range, what do I need to do from there to pivotize the data in that range? BTW, I used to be able to say "R Barry Young" too, but now "M Barry Old" is closer to the truth.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon The OP seemed to be aware of how to make PivotTables so that did not seem to be part of the question or answer.  The easiest way to create a pivot table is through the GUI from the INSERT menu tab (PivotTable is the first ribbon option).  Off-hand,I do not recall how to do it programmaticly, but you can use the macro recorder then make one from the GUI to capture the VBA code for it.

Comment: I don't normally use VBA for creating Excel sheets; I use C#. I have a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37972682/how-can-i-alter-my-pivottable-so-that-it-displays-the-data-in-the-desired-way

Comment: @B.ClayShannon The VBA script will show which Excel Object model/API calls to use.  You will have to convert that to C# and VSTO or the Office Interop yourself, but knowing what the calls are is the hard part IMHO.