# How can I programmatically add a ReportFilter to a PivotTable (Excel Interop/C#)?

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table, filtering, excel-interop

This is a more specific version of the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37972682/how-can-%20i-alter-my-pivottable-so-that-it-displays-the-data-in-the-desired-way).

I am able to generate a PivotTable using this code:

```
private void AddPivotTable()
{
    pivotData = _xlSheet.Range["A1:K1600"];
    pivotDestination = _xlSheet.Range["A1602", useDefault];

    _xlBook.PivotTableWizard(
        Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase,
        pivotData,
        pivotDestination,
        pivotTableName,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        useDefault,
        useDefault,
        false,
        false,
        Excel.XlOrder.xlDownThenOver,
        0,
        useDefault,
        useDefault
    );

    // Set variables used to manipulate the Pivot Table.
    pivotTable = (Excel.PivotTable)_xlSheet.PivotTables(pivotTableName);

    shortnamePivotField = (Excel.PivotField)pivotTable.PivotFields(2);
    itemcodePivotField = (Excel.PivotField)pivotTable.PivotFields(3);
    descriptionPivotField = (Excel.PivotField)pivotTable.PivotFields(4);
    priceweekPivotField = (Excel.PivotField)pivotTable.PivotFields(5);
    weekPivotField = (Excel.PivotField)pivotTable.PivotFields(6);
    pricePivotField = (Excel.PivotField)pivotTable.PivotFields(7);
    regionorderPivotField = (Excel.PivotField)pivotTable.PivotFields(10);

    // Format the Pivot Table.
    pivotTable.Format(Excel.XlPivotFormatType.xlReport2);
    pivotTable.InGridDropZones = false;
    pivotTable.SmallGrid = false;
    pivotTable.ShowTableStyleRowStripes = true;
    pivotTable.TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleLight1";

    // Page Field
    shortnamePivotField.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlPageField;

    // Row Fields
    descriptionPivotField.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
    itemcodePivotField.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;

    // Data Fields
    pricePivotField.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField;
    pricePivotField.Function = Excel.XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum;
}
```

What I want is to be able to create a PivotTable something like this:

[image]

...(which I generated using Excel manually), but as you can see here:

[image]

...trying to accomplish it with the code above is not working. What is needed to programmatically add a ReportFilter to my PivotTable?

### UPDATE

I found a PivotFilter class, but my probes at testing it out:

```
// Pivot Filter
//shortnamePivotFilter.DataField = shortnamePivotField; <= DataField readonly
//shortnamePivotFilter.MemberPropertyField = shortnamePivotField; ""
//shortnamePivotFilter.PivotField = shortnamePivotField; ""
```

...all failed, because PivotFilter's most likely-seeming member properties (*DataField, MemberPropertyField*, and *PivotField*) are all readonly.

### UPDATE 2

With this:

```
//shortnamePivotField.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlPageField;
. . .
shortnamePivotField.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlColumnField;
```

(removing shortnamePivotField as a/the PageField and adding it as a ColumnField) I get this:

[image]

Closer, but no "Seeger" (Turn, turn, turn) yet.

### UPDATE 3

There doesn't seem to be much rhyme, reason, or logic to how things are plopped into the PivotTable. I've got ShortName as a Category Field, Price as a Data Field, and both Description and ItemCode as Row Fields, yet "PRICE" appears as a label in the NW corner (why?) as well as in the ShortName columns (whichever ones are selected from the "CheckedListBox" associated with "SHORT NAME"), while Description and ItemCode are both filterable column headings (like SHORT NAME).

Okay, the Row Fields (Description and ItemCode) determine which rows display, and the Column field determines which Short Name values appear as columns (makes sense), but:

(a) Why is the "PRICE" label vagranting up there in Victoria, British Columbia?

-and:

(b) Why is there a duplicated "Total" row beneath each row? Since each description has its own row, having a Total for that Description simply takes up space without adding any value, eerily reminiscent of congressmen.

### UPDATE 4

I recorded a macro and dragged "SHORT NAME" from the list in ***PivotTable Field List.Choose fields to add to report*** to the Report Filter box in the NW quadrant below it.

The macro recorded as:

```
Sub DragShortNameToReportFilter()
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot Test").PivotFields("SHORT NAME")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-6
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot Test").PivotFields("SHORT NAME").CurrentPage = _
        "(All)"
End Sub
```

...so I tried this C# code:

```
shortnamePivotField.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlColumnField;
shortnamePivotField.Position = 1;
shortnamePivotField.CurrentPage = "(All)";
```

...and this is the result:

[image]

So it worked pretty well as far as it went - but my Row Fields (Description and ItemCode) and Data Field (Price) are now gone or at best invisible/mute.

While the spreadsheet is being created, it now prompts me with, "*Do you want to replace the contents of the destination cells in [Book1]Sheet1?*" (I respond with "OK" but am not overly thrilled with it, not knowing what data I may be thereby replacing).

### UPDATE 5

So I started from "scratch" and first removed all the contents of the boxes (Report Filter, Row Labels, Values) and then added them back with the Macro Recorder faithfully recording. It told me I did this:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot Test").PivotFields("SHORT NAME")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot Test").PivotFields("DESCRIPTION")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot Test").PivotFields("ITEM CODE")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot Test").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "Pivot Test").PivotFields("PRICE"), "Sum of PRICE", xlSum
```

...which doesn't look like much more than I already have in code. I just added the Position values for the two RowFields so that code now looks like this:

```
// Row Fields
descriptionPivotField.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
descriptionPivotField.Position = 1;
itemcodePivotField.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
itemcodePivotField.Position = 2;
```

...but, while better, it's still not quite as nifty as the auto-generated PivotTable...

Comment: Thanks so much for recording your trials and tribulations. The real gem for me is that ALL interop questions can be answered by recording a macro then looking at the source.